# What does tokens and vocab mean in glove embeddings?

Tags: nlp, embedding

I am using glove embeddings and I am quite confused about `tokens` and `vocab` in the embeddings. Like this one:

```
Common Crawl (840B tokens, 2.2M vocab, cased, 300d vectors, 2.03 GB download)
```

what does `tokens` and `vocab` mean, respectively? What is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In NLP tokens refers to the total number of "words" in your corpus. I put words in quotes because the definition varies by task. The vocab is the number of unique "words".

It should be the case that vocab <= tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are obtained after training your corpus and they are not the same size as words.

A word of length 10, tokens of this word maybe 2 or 3 tokens, it basically represents how better you can represent your word and make it mean something to your model.